# WPF treeview from xml file missing attributes (Visual Basic)... xml dataprovider

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net, xaml, treeview

I have been working on building a tree view for some time now and I just can not seem to get it output properly. It is building the tree view like:

1. Candy

- M&M's

2. Vegetables

- Spinach

3. Fruits

- Apples

While that is correct there are more items in each list than just the one. What am I missing or doing wrong to where it is only showing the first item of each list. I do now know much about xml but I do not like how this particular xml is written and it feels wrong to me, but I am not in a place to be able to edit it. Is it possible to get the entire list showing w/o changing the xml? If so, how?

```
The code is:
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlFile}
,XPath=//@Name}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding XPath=.}">
                     <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=..//@Foodname}"/> 
                     </StackPanel>
               </TreeViewItem>
          </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>




The XML for that is:
<Foods>
    <UnhealthyFoods Name ="Candy"/>
        <Food Foodname = "M&M's" />
        </Food>
        <Food Foodname = "Skittles" />
        </Food>
        <Food Foodname = "Starburst" />
        </Food>
    </UnhealthyFoods>
    <HealthyFoods>
        <FoodGroup1 Name ="Vegetables"/>
        <Food Foodname = "Spinach" />
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Brocolli" />
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Greens" />
            </Food>
    </FoodGroup1>
    </HealthyFoods>
    <HealthyFoods>
        <FoodGroup2 Name ="Fruits"/>
        <Food Foodname = "Apples" />
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Pears" />
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Cherries" />
            </Food>
    </FoodGroup2>
    </HealthyFoods>
</Foods>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Textblock line to a list view worked as intended. Don't know if this is the best or most efficient way but it works for now. Open to more suggestions